# htaccess redirect https to http except specific pages

Tags: redirect, htaccess, .htaccess

I want to redirect https to http for almost all pages, except for checkout, cart and account. Especially to improve speed.

How do I define that inside my htaccess?

All my rewrite rules in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/customer/account/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wishlist/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ebizautoresponder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/dashboard/index/key/
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

##### Block unwanted Crawler Bots that clog your server #####

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MJ12bot
RewriteRule .* - [F]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} 80legs [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

I use these settings for secure and unsecure:

[image]

Comment: why do you need htaccess redirects. Magento should handle the redirects automatically.

Comment: Do you want to do via htacessess only ? you can do it magento way in file:

/ app /code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/config.xml

find:
<frontend>
<secure_url>

and insert:
<checkout_cart>/checkout/cart</checkout_cart>

So it looks like this:
<frontend>
<secure_url>
<checkout_cart>/checkout/cart</checkout_cart>
<checkout_onepage>/checkout/onepage</checkout_onepage>
<checkout_multishipping>/checkout/multishipping</checkout_multishipping>
</secure_url>

Comment: @Marius No the problem is that Magento does not preform this correct. Because all normal pages are available trough http and https. And it is not redirecting correct to https on checkout

Comment: @Jelle. I see. I misunderstood your question. I though you wanted the other way around. Sorry for butting in then.

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar Thanks, but does that redirect all other pages trough http? Because otherwise I will create duplicate content, because the page is available on http and also on https.

Comment: @Marius No problem, but do you know the best solution to this problem?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea. Will post if I find something.

Comment: @Marius Thanks! But a lot of other Magento users should have this problem, right? That they only want to use https on the checkout and cart. All other pages I want to load over http because of the speed. But in that case all other pages should also redirect to http, when they navigate to the page over https.

Comment: You do know https is a positive Google ranking factor right? If you're worried about duplicate content (which you shouldn't if it's duplicate content from your own website), you'd do better by redirecting everything to https instead of half to http.

Comment: @Jelle, if you use SSL offloading the speed impact will be minimal, all of my shops are full ssl and most have an average pageload of +- 1 second. Doing this because of speed isn't really a valid reason, sounds to me like you should look for your performance improvements on another level.

Comment: @ToonVanDooren The setting of SSL offloading is default by Magento. What is a better setting for this, to improve speed? Because also our entire store runs on SSL.

Comment: You might want to check on the concept of offloading. Having a proxy in front of your Magento that handles SSL is what we call SSL offloading.

http://www.ehow.com/facts_7519825_ssl-offloading.html

The impact of SSL is neglectable anyways, look at it as a small drop in a whole pond. If you want performance increase look into your code both backend and frontend. If you want to go even faster, use Varnish.
Going full SSL is also better for SEO as @MilanSimek stated...

Comment: Just worth noting that not all HTTPS termination is equal. A badly selected cipher list, out of date OpenSSL build, poor SSL server, old generation hardware etc. will all lead to potentially huge performance degradation when using HTTPS. If you do deploy HTTPS site wide, it needs to be on a perfectly configured, modern, hardware accelerated stack - else you'll just see slow down.

Comment: @BenLessani-Sonassi agreed, but that is something I haven't seen in a long while :D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have so for should work pretty well. The actuall redirect part I've added below

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/customer/account/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wishlist/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ebizautoresponder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/dashboard/index/key/
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks. But the checkout redirects to http://www.domain.com/index.php

Comment: Did you set the right safe and unsafe base urls in Magento backend?

Comment: Yes I did, these settings are correct. Also for the customer account, it redirects to to domain.com/index.php

Comment: See my safe and unsafe base urls settings, is this correct? Off course I removed my domain.

Comment: Can you update your question with all of you rewrite rules in the htaccess?

Comment: I updated my question with all rewrite rules in my htaccess

Comment: Do you know why the checkout is redirect to http://www.domain.com/index.php. All normal http pages works fine with your rule.

Comment: @Jelle sorry, was at a conference so no time to check it out. Will take a look tonight

Comment: @HenkZ I have the same problem. With similar rewrite rules, everything works fine except those pages that supposed to be on https will be redirected to index.php. I just couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

As I got from the comments, you are worrying about duplicate content.

1.***Duplicate content should not be an issue for the admin pages ;***

**2.** You should ***actually serve pages which belong to the customer or checkout pages via https as this is a matter of security***. I don't see a duplicate content problem if those pages are always served via https which is the case in the Magento default configuration. ***If http and https is enabled, those pages will always be served via https only***.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do know the reason to serve some pages over https. But I want to serve all other pages only over http. Also when these pages are requested over https, the shop should redirect the user to http. But I can't find a way to redirect always to http and only in the cart and checkout to https.

Comment: Actually thats the default behaviour in Magento?! If the option "Use secure URLs in Frontend" is enabled, customer account and checkout will be redirected from http to https, the rest is still running on http.

Comment: And for the admin area, enable "Use secure URLs in Admin"

Comment: Correct, but all these other pages are not redirecting to http, when navigating to https. Because that is not how it works default on Magento.

Comment: Ah... I see! Sorry for being so slow :P

Comment: No problem! ;-) I want to redirect all normal pages to http and only checkout and account on https

Comment: Then something like Sanders answer ;-)

Comment: http and https versions of your page count as 'non-malicious' duplicate content: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en. So no need to worry about that for SEO purposes

Comment: I think this deserves creating a seperate answer here @MilanSimek :)